# Как задать ссылку на строку кода веб-страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, ссылки, браузер

Поскольку не на всех страницах в интернете авторы указывают локальные ссылки на определенные разделы (абзацы, заголовки и т д), хотелось бы узнать, существуют ли методы, подобно указанию локальной ссылки (якоря), но при этом позволяющие ссылаться на строку кода веб-страницы, подобно механизму работы консоли ошибок, и именно так, как метод локальной ссылки - с прокручиванием страницы до нужного элемента?

P.S.: хотелось бы ещё узнать, возможно было бы указывать и координату по вертикали - столбец, автоматизированно (при выделении фрагмента с работающим  скриптом) чтобы задавать JS промежуток, который он будет "подсвечивать" при переходе по сформированной им же ссылке таким образом.

Comment: Вообще ничего не понятно...